# Is it possible to get response from post parameters without querystring?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to show response after transaction  done without query string   in post parameters.Is it possible? If possible any one can help me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Post request data is always sent without using Query string. Just make the form method as POST like this

```
<form method="post" ....
```

or if you are making an Ajax call, then just specify the type as POST like this

```
$.Ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    other fields
})
```

Comment: I tried post method but i got an error like " the http verb post  "/.htm " path is not allowed"

Comment: You have to design your handler method with a post attribute. Which technology stack are you using?